# Google Webmaster tools restricted to certain pages only

Tags: google-search-console

Is it possible to give someone access to webmaster tools, but restrict their access to specific pages only?

We have a franchise and each franchisee might have their own SEO people who at the moment are asking for access to the Webmaster tools. But, we can't give them full access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now that's not possible.

Comment: Any recommendations? I know these SEO guys are going to insist.

Comment: The best thing I can think of is to create reports and email them to them weekly or monthly.

Comment: You can restrict per subdomain, if that is a possible option for you.